# Segmentation fault 11 when running pygame in Sublime Text 3

Tags: python, pygame, sublimetext3

I am using Python 3.4.0 and I have Mac OSX 10.9.2. I have the following code saved as sublimePygame in Sublime Text.

```
import pygame, sys 
from pygame.locals import * 

pygame.init() 

#set up the window
DISPLAYSURF = pygame.display.set_mode((400, 300)) 
pygame.display.set_caption('Drawing') 

# set up the colors 
BLACK = ( 0, 0, 0) 
WHITE = (255, 255, 255) 
RED = (255, 0, 0) 
GREEN = ( 0, 255, 0) 
BLUE = ( 0, 0, 255)

# Draw on surface object
DISPLAYSURF.fill(WHITE)
pygame.draw.polygon(DISPLAYSURF, GREEN, ((146, 0), (291, 106), (236, 277), (56, 277), (0,        106))) 
pygame.draw.line(DISPLAYSURF, BLUE, (60, 60), (120, 60), 4) 
pygame.draw.line(DISPLAYSURF, BLUE, (120, 60), (60, 120)) 
pygame.draw.line(DISPLAYSURF, BLUE, (60, 120), (120, 120), 4) 
pygame.draw.circle(DISPLAYSURF, BLUE, (300, 50), 20, 0) 
pygame.draw.ellipse(DISPLAYSURF, RED, (300, 250, 40, 80), 1) 
pygame.draw.rect(DISPLAYSURF, RED, (200, 150, 100, 50)) 


pixObj = pygame.PixelArray(DISPLAYSURF) 
pixObj[480, 380] = BLACK 
pixObj[482, 382] = BLACK 
pixObj[48, 384] = BLACK 
pixObj[486, 386] = BLACK 
pixObj[488, 388] = BLACK 
del pixObj 

while True: # main game loop 
    for event in pygame.event.get(): 
        if event.type == QUIT: 
            sys.exit() 
            pygame.display.update()
```

I ran the code in my terminal and the python window opened for a second and then closed.

I got this error in the terminal.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sublimePygame", line 29, in <module>
    pixObj[480, 380] = BLACK 
IndexError: invalid index
Segmentation fault: 11
```

I checked the pygame documentation and my code seemed ok. I googled the error and *Segmentation Error 11* seems to be a bug in python but I read that it was fixed in Python 3.4.0.

Does Anyone know what went wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Edit: Marius found the bug in my program, however when I run it it opens a blank Python window and not what it was supposed top open. Does anyone know why this happened?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see a definite bug in your code, but I'm not sure if that's causing a segmentation fault, which is a more serious error.

The bug in your code is that you create a 400x300 window:

```
DISPLAYSURF = pygame.display.set_mode((400, 300))
```

And then try to set colour values for pixels that are outside the bounds of that window

```
pixObj[480, 380] = BLACK
```

Again, this might not be causing the segmentation fault.

Comment: Thanks! That really helped.Now when I run _Segmentation Error:11_ no longer happens however it opens a blank python window and not the drawings that I was expecting to see.

Answer (score 0):

Your blank python window problem is here:

```
while True: # main game loop 
    for event in pygame.event.get(): 
        if event.type == QUIT: 
            sys.exit() 
            pygame.display.update()
```

`pygame.display.update()` will only be executed if QUIT is activated. You need to remove some of the indents so that it is outside the for loop, but within the while loop.